# A SQLiteConnection was leaked

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a problem with a SQLite connection. When my Activity load, logCat say:

```
A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/org.witixradio.app/databases/database.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

I checked my database access and I don't find where I keep a connection opened.

here is my code:

```
public ListeurPlanning(Activity _activity, ListView _view, String jour) {
 PlanningDAO listing = new PlanningDAO(activity);
Cursor c = listing.selectionnerDay(jour);
    c.moveToFirst();
if(c.getCount()<=0) {
        repertoire[0][0] = "Playlist";
        repertoire[0][1] = "0h-24h";
        repertoire[0][2] = "Playlist";
    }else {
// I do a lot of stuff with my cursor
}
c.close();
```

I close my cursor after usage so I don't think that my problem is here.
now the code of PlanningDAO class:

```
public class PlanningDAO extends DAOBasePlanning{
public static final String PLANNING_KEY = "id";
public static final String PLANNING_JOUR = "jour";
public static final String PLANNING_HEURE_DEBUT = "heuredebut";
public static final String PLANNING_HEURE_FIN = "heurefin";
public static final String PLANNING_ANIM = "anim";
public static final String PLANNING_EMISSION = "emission";

public static final String PLANNING_TABLE_NAME = "Planning";
public static final String PLANNING_TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + PLANNING_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                PLANNING_KEY + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                PLANNING_JOUR + " TEXT, " +
                PLANNING_HEURE_DEBUT + " INTEGER, " +
                PLANNING_HEURE_FIN + " INTEGER, " +
                PLANNING_ANIM + " TEXT, " +
                PLANNING_EMISSION + " TEXT)";
public static final String PLANNING_TABLE_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PLANNING_TABLE_NAME + ";";


/**
 *  le métier à ajouter à la base
 */
PlanningDAO(Context pContext) {
    super(pContext);
}

public void ajouter(Planning p) {
    ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
    value.put(PlanningDAO.PLANNING_JOUR, p.getJour());
    value.put(PlanningDAO.PLANNING_HEURE_DEBUT, p.gethoraireDebut());
    value.put(PlanningDAO.PLANNING_HEURE_FIN, p.gethoraireFin());
    value.put(PlanningDAO.PLANNING_ANIM, p.getAnimateur());
    value.put(PlanningDAO.PLANNING_EMISSION, p.getEmission());
    mDb.insert(PlanningDAO.PLANNING_TABLE_NAME, null, value);

}

/**
 * @param id l'identifiant du métier à supprimer
 */
public void supprimer(long id) {
        mDb.delete(PLANNING_TABLE_NAME, PLANNING_KEY + " = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});

    }

public void purge(){
    mDb.delete(PLANNING_TABLE_NAME,null,null);

}

/**
 * @param id l'identifiant du métier à récupérer
 */
public Cursor selectionner(long id) {
    Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("select * from " + PLANNING_TABLE_NAME + " where id = ?", new String[]{Long.toString(id)});

    return c;
}

public Cursor selectionnerAll() {
    Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("select * from " + PLANNING_TABLE_NAME + " where id > ?", new String[]{"0"});

    return c;
}

public Cursor selectionnerDay(String jour){
    Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("select * from " + PLANNING_TABLE_NAME + " where jour = ? ORDER BY heuredebut", new String[]{jour});
    return c;
}


}
```

And now my DAOBasePlanning class:

```
public abstract class DAOBasePlanning {
// Nous sommes à la première version de la base
// Si je décide de la mettre à jour, il faudra changer cet attribut
protected final static int VERSION = 3;
// Le nom du fichier qui représente ma base
protected final static String NOM = "database.db";

protected SQLiteDatabase mDb = null;
protected DatabaseHandlerPlanning mHandler = null;

public DAOBasePlanning(Context pContext) {
    this.mHandler = new DatabaseHandlerPlanning(pContext, NOM, null, VERSION);
}

public SQLiteDatabase open() {
    // Pas besoin de fermer la dernière base puisque getWritableDatabase s'en charge
    mDb = mHandler.getWritableDatabase();
    return mDb;
}

public void close() {
    mDb.close();
}

public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
    return mDb;
}
}
```

I have read a lot of questions about this subject but I can't find the reason of my problem

Maybe you have an idea.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call `close()` on the `PlanningDAO` object. Thus, its `mDB` reference never gets closed - and leaks.

Comment: Oh yes in my listeurplanning I don't call listing.close(); I'm so stupid. Thanks a lot for your help